250001: Could not connect to Snowflake backend after 2 attempt(s).Aborting
I am trying to connect to snowflake using sql database and snowflake url but I am getting "Could not connect error".
This is the code that I am using:
from langchain import OpenAI, SQLDatabase
from snowflake.snowpark import Session
from langchain.chains import create_sql_query_chain


snowflake_account = "XXXXX"
username = "xxxx"
password = "xxxxxxx"
database= "eg_db"
schema = "eg_sc"
warehouse = "COMPUTE_WH"
role = "ACCOUNTADMIN"

snowflake_url = f"snowflake://{username}:{password}@{snowflake_account}/{database}/{schema}?      warehouse={warehouse}&role={role}"

db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(snowflake_url, sample_rows_in_table_info=1, include_tables=['table1','table2'])

print(db.table_info)

I checked my snowflake account and tried varies options like:
orgname-accountname orgname-accountname.region.cloud(gcp) accountname.region.cloud(gcp) locator.region.cloud(gcp)
Can someone help to resolve this error?

This  error can be related to using an incorrect account identifier while trying to connect to Snowflake, can you check if with the same values you are able to connect using the browser or Snowsql

check if you can use external browser option instead of user pass.

When I am using snowflake connector that is this code: " import snowflake.connector
try:
conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
user="xxxx",
password="xxxxxx",
account="orgname-accountname",
database="eg_db",
schema="eg_sc",
warehouse="COMPUTE_WH",
role="ACCOUNTADMIN"
)
print("Connection successful")
except Exception as e:
print(f"Error: {e}")" I am able to connect to snowflake and run queries and get output as well, its when I am using snowflake url and sql database it is throwing an error

I am not sure if the connection mechanism which you are using is the right one. This "f"snowflake://{username}:{password}@{snowflake_account}/{database}/{schema}?" is not the right url format for connecting to snowflake. We need to pass the auth type to ensure that username password is accepted by the account.
Based on what I read in your question, you would need to user EXTERNALBROWSER mechanism as detailed here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use#setting-up-browser-based-sso

This error appears when the account identifier is incorrect.
The combinations used for the account identifier seem to be slightly mistaken.
Please follow the below syntax for building the Snowflake account identifier-

account_locator.cloud_region_id or account_locator.cloud_region_id.cloud

For example, if your account locator is xy12345:
If the account is located in the AWS US East (Ohio) region, additional segments are required, and the account identifier would be xy12345.us-east-2.aws

orgname-account_name

For example, if your orgname is ab6789 and your account_name is xy1234 then, your account identifier would be ab6789-xy1234
Please refer to the below documentation for more information related to Snowflake account identifier-
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier

Thanks a ton - was beating my head in over this one.
